# "Error: Please select a valid Python interpreter" in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been asked to use **Python** in **Pycharm** and, after downloading it, I have found a problem which doesn't allow me to compile anything because there is an `"Error: Please select a valid Python interpreter"`. I know there are similar questions already solved that propose solutions to this problem but I have revised those solutions and none of them is satisfactory for me. I would appreciate help very much. I let you here also some screenshots that show the error:

Comment: Well, I am not allowed to put the images because I am a new contributor but I think there's a link to them. Anyway, other related things that Pycharm say to me are "No Python Interpreter configured for the project".

Comment: have you download the python interpreter?

Comment: Yes, several times in fact.

Comment: can you see the `Select Run/Debug Configuration` at the top right corner, right beside the `run` button

Comment: click that dropdown and select the `Edit Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

Try reading through these docs, even has pictures.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and only provide the link for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm click `ctrl+alt+s` (on windows) and if there is no interpreter as shown then...

1. Click add Interpreter

[image]

2. Select Virtual Env and Click New radio button and then press ok as shown in picture.This will resolve your issue.

[image]